# According to current coding standards, is it valid to add reference to the function name in function definition?

Tags: php, function, reference, coding-style, function-definition

I'm using **PHP 7.1.11**

In the PHP Manual I come across some very different code which is as below :

```
<?php
  function &get_instance_ref() {
    static $obj;

    echo 'Static object: ';
    var_dump($obj);
    if (!isset($obj)) {
      // Assign a reference to the static variable
      $obj = &new stdclass;
    }
    $obj->property++;
    return $obj;
  }

  function &get_instance_noref() {
    static $obj;

    echo 'Static object: ';
    var_dump($obj);
    if (!isset($obj)) {
      // Assign the object to the static variable
      $obj = new stdclass;
    }
    $obj->property++;
    return $obj;
  }

  $obj1 = get_instance_ref();
  $still_obj1 = get_instance_ref();
  echo "\n";
  $obj2 = get_instance_noref();
  $still_obj2 = get_instance_noref();
?>
```

Output of the above code is as below :

```
Static object: NULL
Static object: NULL

Static object: NULL
Static object: object(stdClass)(1) {
["property"]=>
int(1)
}
```

I didn't understand the above code at all because for the first time in my career I'm seeing that a reference got prepended to the function name in its function definition. So, from first line itself the code is giving me hard time of my life.

Someone please explain me what's happening over here in above code?

What's the intention behind using reference in function definition? Doesn't this style of coding make simple things hard?

Is this a valid coding style according to currently available **PHP Coding Standards?**

Comment: None. What you have there is an antipattern. Stop abusing references.

Comment: @tereško : I have not written this code. It's from the PHP manual itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the reference operator (&) in the function declaration to return a reference from a function (ie: rather than a "value").  In that case you should also use the reference operator when assigning the returned value to a variable in the calling code (ie: outside of the function).

See example #3 in the following link as well as the description before it:

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php